# Monetize an UWP service with recurring payments

Tags: win-universal-app

I an UWP app I want to monetize a service via monthly or yearly payments. The store currently does not offer recurring payments. How can one implement this with the IAP features currently available?

Can a user buy an expired durable product again, or will the licensing API report "product was already purchased" even though it is no longer active?
Would offering a consumable product be a good solution, e.g. "1 month of servicex usage", so the user can buy another n months?

UPDATE:

I implemented my service as a consumable product but there seems to be no built-in way for this "license" to [survive an app uninstall](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/fb299024-2289-4bd0-b500-9a45c3c75566/uwpc-consumable-inapp-products-app-uninstall?forum=wpdevelop).

I am now considering using an expiring durable product and checking its ExpirationDate plus a grace period instead of .IsActive like this:

```
Function IsFeatureAllowed() As Boolean
    Return (ProductLicenses(myProductID).ExpirationDate - DateTime.Now).Days + GracePeriodDays > 0
End Function

Sub OfferNewLicense()
    If Not IsFeatureAllowed(myProductID) Then
        ShowInteractiveToast($"Your myProductID license has expired. Get myProductID?")
    Else
        If (ProductLicenses(myProductID).ExpirationDate - DateTime.Now).Days < 1 Then
            Dim daysRemaining = ProductLicenses(myProductID).ExpirationDate - DateTime.Now).Days + GracePeriodDays
            ShowInteractiveToast($"Your myProductID license will expire in {daysRemaining} days.Get myProductID?")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Should this work? I see now way to reliably test this with the CurrentAppSimulator.

UPDATE:
Using a grace period via testing the ExpirationDate only does not work because the store unexpectedly returns DateTime.Max for inactive products (I expected DateTime.Min).

Comment: Typically if you want your app to have a "subscription" to use it you would handle the payments on your website.  You would also have to check the user has a valid subscription before letting them in

Comment: I am looking for a simpler solution using built-in store features. See update to my question.